# Access report summing data after the filtering

Tags: sql-server, report, ms-access-2007, filtering

Here is the structure, we're using Access 2007 with SQL Server. We've got the query established that extracts the data we are looking for and then filtering on a specific ID. The query results are then reported on. On the report we need to have a sum of the field "Amount" on the report. Here is the problem, the report is processing the running sum on the entire database and not on the filtered query results.

I've tried changing the report running sum parameters with no success. As well as establishing grouping, but naturally there is only one group, so that is not really successful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you specify the datasource to your report?

You may open the report this way...

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewPreview, , "Id = " & MyId
```

Or This way...

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewPreview, , , , "Id = " & myId
.......
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Me.RecordSource = "Select fields from view where " & OpenArgs
End Sub
```

Comment: We use more variables to process the commands, but yes basically that is how it is stated.

Comment: strID = Me.Number

stDocName = "Report Detail by ID"
strWhereCond = "[ID] = " & strID
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, strWhereCond

Comment: There must be one ore comma, before strWhereCond, like this "DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , strWhereCond"

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay. I'm only at this client site twice a week. Was there yesterday and added the missing comma. Must have stared at the line of code for hours. Never saw the missing comma. Figured it was something I was missing. Neither myself nor the dba saw it. It works great now. On to new problems. Thanks so much.

Comment: Ok, then validate my answer please... :)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first posting. I did not know that would be beneficial for you. If checking the posting is validation, then I've done it. If not please direct me, I'm very happy to do that for you. Stackoverflow is becoming my go to place for answers. Better than Microsoft. I want to help the community.

Comment: Great! Now there is one more thing, you can also vote my answer, as i did for your question :).

Answer (score 0):

In the control you wish to display the sum, enter this into the ControlSource property:

```
=Sum(Nz([Amount],0))
```

See if that helps you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Nz function. I did enter that into the ControlSource and I was rewarded with an illegal operation. Does the SQL command include this function or is it only available in Access? Not encountering problems with null values.

Comment: @user3814142: Nz replaces null values with the selected value, as I'm sure you researched.  Not sure how the SUM function is implemented here, SQL-esque or VBA, to be honest.  You can take a look here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/access-help/summing-in-reports-HA001122444.aspx.  I'm not sure why you are getting an illegal operation, though.  Seems not directly related to the functions themselves, I am inclined to think.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have tried using the group with a running sum over the group, but I did not do as the article outlines. I will try that tomorrow. It is probably something simple I am missing. Thanks for info.